# Does the Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office support Office 2007

Tags: c#, ms-office, openxml-sdk, office-2007

If I browse to the [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb456487%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and select "Other Versions" > "Office 2007", it takes me to [Open XML Format SDK 1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb456487%28v=office.12%29.aspx). Does this mean that the Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office does not support Office 2007 officially?

**Edit:**

[It would seem that it is valid to work with Office 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd440953%28v=office.12%29.aspx) but that still makes me wonder about why the above happens, just to suggest you should use Office 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open XML supports all files that use the Open XML standard (xlsx, docx etc..). That includes office 2007 documents..

See http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124 for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its that 2007 is limited compared to 2010 and all the abilities of the SDK 2.0 will not work in 2007. SO yes and no to your comment.

2007 can render the same document differently even though the feature is supported in both products.

I had created a table in word with an outer border only, I did not declare any type of inner border at all. This worked great in word 2010, but in 2007 it actually created borders on the inner cells also. It was an easy fix of just declaring the inner cells to not have borders.

I think it is stuff like that and the added features is why the MS page switches you to 1.0